# Django Order_by Not working on FloatField

Tags: django

## Order_by not working in FloatField type Django

## models.py

```
class CourseCategory(models.Model):
        category = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=False)
        description = models.TextField(blank=True)
        class Meta(object):
            app_label = "course_category"
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.category
```

## Coursetrack Model

```
 class CourseTrack(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(CourseCategory)
        course_id = CourseKeyField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
        tracks = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
        active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        class Meta(object):
            app_label = "course_category"
        def __unicode__(self):
            return str(self.course_id)
```

## TopCoursesCategory

```
class TopCoursesCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(CourseCategory)
    class Meta(object):
        app_label = "course_category"
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.category)
```

## I added here order_by(), as you can see but its not working.

## view.py

```
def get_popular_courses_ids():
    popular_category_id = CourseCategory.objects.filter(category='Popular')
    popular_courses_ids = CourseTrack.objects.values('course_id').filter(category=popular_category_id).order_by('tracks')
    course_id_list = []
    for course_id in popular_courses_ids:
        course_id_list.append(course_id['course_id'])
    return course_id_list
```

Comment: But do you get the output for popular_courses_ids?

Comment: Are you sure that all the selected rows have some 'value' in that column?

Answer (score 0):

I think the query you have posted is wrong.

You have used the following lines.

```
popular_category_id = CourseCategory.objects.filter(category='Popular')
popular_courses_ids = CourseTrack.objects.values('course_id').filter(category=popular_category_id).order_by('tracks')
```

In the first line, you have used `filter` and you have used the resulting variable as `category=` in your second query which you cannot do. For `category=` in your second query to work, you would need to give a single element and not a queryset. Replace your `filter` with `get` in the first query and it might work fine.

Or

If you think that popular_category_id can have more than one row for the category `popular`, leave the first query as it is and change your second query to

```
popular_courses_ids = CourseTrack.objects.values('course_id').filter(category__in=popular_category_id).order_by('tracks')
```

I have changed `category` to `category__in`.

Comment: Thanks Vishal. I have posted all the models please see it again and tell me whats the wrong

Comment: I have explained what could have gone wrong in my post.. Please read it